# clone quote with new quote id (duplicate invoiceID, paypal)

Tags: paypal, quote

Is it possible to generate a new quote object with the exact contents (and all other information) from an old quote object?  I'm getting a duplicate invoice id error from paypal and it seems that generating a new quote would resolve this issue (quoteID == invoiceID).

Comment: Can anyone help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new Quote object and use the merge() method on it, passing the source Quote as parameter.